# Can't declare applicable version range in "syntax" section on documentation beta

Tags: feature-request, bug, documentation

In the "Syntax" section, it appears not to be possible to insert version fences.

All attempts result in the markdown

- not rendering the version exclusion
- deeming the code illegal when I submit for review ( because the comment line doesn't satisfy the bullet point criteria )

Have I misunderstood the purpose of this? Or just an oversight?

Comment: Versioning, as a whole, needs work @KentFredric. Thanks for the feedback (even as you noticed it quite early on) - we are capturing this and others to better address in Docs v2, while at present we are heads down pursuing the [MVP TSQL experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349409/what-t-sql-documentation-has-helped-you).

Answer (score 1):

Currently syntax can *only* be a list of one-liner examples/descriptors of syntax. That is, it cannot hold *anything* else (such as block text, version fence markdown, etc).

IMO this is very restrictive for a lot of languages that are documented, even C, for example, could benefit from allowing somethings, such as version fence markdown, within the syntax section. This bug should be a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) for adding version fence markdown allowance to the syntax section.

For version demarcation in particular, the current convention seems to be to abandon version fence markdown within the syntax section, instead using a line to display a language comment to the same effect. See `// since C99` in [C's Loops topic syntax section](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/5151/iteration-statements-loops-for-while-do-while#t=201706071337399921156&a=syntax)