# What T-SQL documentation has helped you?

Tags: discussion, documentation

> **The Documentation beta has [ended](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation).** We'd like to thank you all for the input on this meta question. It'll be useful to have the question and it's answers around, should we attempt another Documentation-like product. In the meantime, we are no longer accepting new answers.

---

As you may have [heard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349410/tearing-down-the-structure-of-documentation), we are revisiting the basics of documentation  and are going to run a true Minimum Viable Product ([what is this?](http://theleanstartup.com/principles)) experiment, that enables way more user input cycles and learnings. I encourage you to read our [original announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349410/tearing-down-the-structure-of-documentation) for more of the details.

Our experiment is to build a few great pages of Transact-SQL documentation, first, in a new, lightweight version of docs, so as to learn what's needed. To that end, we'd like to **understand how current docs/reference materials serve you**.

Specifically, what T-SQL reference materials have helped you? What's good about them and what could be better? Did the structure and elements help or hinder their usefulness? What if anything was missing/hard to find?

If you haven't used T-SQL or Microsoft SQL Server, you aren't out of luck. Reference materials from other SQL variants will probably *also* be useful especially if it's different from what's available for T-SQL.

**Please focus on what makes the existing SQL documentation useful and what is missing or could be better.** If you mostly used the [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) to figure out how to get things done, feel free to point out gaps that could be filled by Stack Overflow Documentation.

Comment: For reference, the TSQL set of docs can be found in http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/topics , and the official ms docs are here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference

Comment: Advanced techniques, such as the various ways to structure trees/hierarchical data with pros/cons/optimizations would likely be pretty useful and is something that can't be found in the existing documentation. [Here's an example from wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) But... with the existance of the page on wikipedia, and how well it's done, would such an article really have a place on SODocs?

Comment: Great point and good share, @KevinB. To me, the fact that the official docs lack it and advanced users can find it at another spot, does make a site that has all of this in one place sound valuable! A site perhaps, that makes content easy to find and contains progression (beginner -> advanced). Potentially it's the only place one needs to go to, to get all the details on said technology - the what (definitions), the why (pros and cons) and the how (best practices, examples, code snippets, advanced techniques). But we don't know that yet - and we are gonna start with this simple experiment!

Comment: Google and the MSDN, and SO when things get tricky. There's no gap for SO Docs to fill. :P

Comment: "Reference materials from other SQL variants will probably also be useful especially if it's different from what's available for T-SQL." What does this mean, are you suggesting the T-SQL users might find reference materials about PL/SQL or pgplsql etc useful in certain circumstances, or that the TSQL topic will have fuzzy edges? If the former case I think that would be very doubtful as the extra noise would be far greater than any extra signal.

Comment: @JackDouglas neither. The statement was made solely from a learning and discovery aspect - as in - we'd be happy to hear your thoughts on what's good/bad/missing in other variants of SQL as well, if T-SQL isn't an area you are familiar with.

Comment: I understand now — that makes perfect sense then :)

Comment: Perhaps those engaged in this experiment will find some inspiration in O'Reilly's [Transact-SQL Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565927568.do). Isn't the intent of such a book to go beyond what can be learned from the official documentation? That said, some would argue that the topics in this book and books like it would fit nicely in Q&A. (BTW, I'm not a T-SQL guy.)

Comment: ...And with respect to Q&A, I would find it helpful to hear views on how the T-SQL documentation might differ from the topic list that is presented via the query [Highest Voted 'tsql' Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql). Isn't the result of this query a good indication of those T-SQL "tasks" that are of greatest interest to the T-SQL community? (Another measure would be ranking questions by page views.)

Comment: I wonder if this question should be marked as somehow ... deprecated? Since Documentation is getting "sunsetted"?

Comment: @Mike How's "can no longer be reproduced" for you?

Comment: @Tiny Ha! Works fine :).

Answer (score 22):

One thing I've never been big on is the syntax structure (ABNF or whatever it is). I want to know how to create a stored procedure that returns some data. I go to [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql) and get four different syntaxes. The first one starts with:

```
CREATE [ OR ALTER ] { PROC | PROCEDURE } [schema_name.] procedure_name [ ; number ]
```

Umm... okay... I just want to create a procedure; do I have to type in brackets? The first "Simple Example" is three pages lower (on my monitor anyway). And that first example is:

```
CREATE PROC What_DB_is_this     
AS   
SELECT DB_NAME() AS ThisDB;
```

Really? Getting the name of the database? I'm guessing that if I'm Joe Developer, having been tasked with creating a sproc, I'm not going to want to get the name of the database, which I need to know in order to connect.

Now, that said, they have a pretty good set of [examples lower down on the page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql#a-nameexamplesa-examples). I especially like the examples around parameters, which show examples with `OUTPUT` parameters; even one with a table-valued parameter.

I like the idea of task-based organization. So, stuff like:

- I know I need to get some data out of SQL Server that's stored with an Id and a ParentId, and I want to get that data out as hierarchical data. How do I do that? What are some of the gotchas with that pattern?
- I want to have a single statement that will update or insert data as needed, then return the existing or new id of that row. How do I do that? What are some of the gotchas with that pattern?

That's what I'd like to see.

Answer (score 20):

In order to get a broad handle on SQL syntax (not just the details of a single specific clause), the most effective documentation I've seen is the SQLite official documentation, which makes use of railroad diagrams:

### [sql-stmt](https://sqlite.org/syntax/sql-stmt.html)

[image: Railroad diagram of SQL statement]

### [select-stmt](https://sqlite.org/syntax/select-stmt.html)

[image: Railroad diagram of SELECT statement]

Each diagram is accompanied by links to the sub-pieces of the syntax. For example, from [select-stmt](https://sqlite.org/syntax/select-stmt.html) you can get to [expr](https://sqlite.org/syntax/expr.html), [join-clause](https://sqlite.org/syntax/join-clause.html) or [table-or-subquery](https://sqlite.org/syntax/table-or-subquery.html). (Nitpick -- it would be nice if the links were embedded in the diagram.)

I think it would be an extremely powerful method of documentation for SQL (and other declarative languages -- I am thinking of LINQ here.) Unfortunately, these cannot be easily generated fro the T-SQL official documentation, which (1) uses an odd variant of BNF, and (2) is not always syntactically correct, and (3) is sometimes incorrect in describing the SQL syntax.

Comment: Your nitpick is far form a nitpick, I'd say having an image map would be a big usability boost. For example, if I wanted to know what `RECURSIVE` was good for, it would be nice if it was a link to the topic that covers it (`common-table-expression`), which may not be immediately obvious from the keyword. You are right that generating such diagrams isn't easy for T-SQL, though. The best we have at the moment is an [independent but official T-SQL parser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser), but that's not the same as a grammar.

Comment: Yeah, in my opinion, automated links ("used by" at the bottom here) are one of the most important missing features in Docs.SO.

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349468/4137916) mentions a syntax I've never seen in all my years of working with SQL Server: `; number`. Scrolling down, it was apparently introduced in SQL Server 2008, and the documentation states that it's deprecated. That's just the sort of thing I wouldn't want to see in a main topic at all, just in the one that explicitly covered the entire syntax in case I encountered this in the wild and had to know what it means. An interactive railroad diagram could leave such things collapsed by default. (Or leave it to the official docs altogether.)

Comment: Diagrams can be powerful illustrations of concepts. (Personally, I don't find them very helpful (I guess I'm not a visual learner?), but I know others do.) Being able to explore the diagram via links is also a great idea. Out of curiosity, what do you think of the rest of SQLite's documentation? Are there other useful bits we could <strike>steal</strike> learn from?

Comment: You could use d3.js and not use images at all.

Comment: I like diagrams when they simplify complex topics. But that second diagram just makes my head spin.

Comment: @JonEricson My point was not the use of diagrams in general, but the specific use of railroad diagrams in explaining SQL syntax; and more generally, any syntax that has a start and end point, and has various required or optional subparts; I suspect that trying to document the syntax of an imperative language using a railroad diagram would be less useful. Regarding the rest of the SQLite documentation, it's been some time since I've had need for it; I only brought this up because I found it sorely lacking when trying to pick up some complicated bit of T-SQL syntax.

Comment: @Suragch If the diagram was interactive -- that you could collapse and expand various parts -- would that be better?

Comment: @ZevSpitz, yes, that would be better. I tend to think what would help me more, though, would be a plain list of keywords with simple examples of how they are used.

Comment: @Suragch _a plain list of keywords with simple examples of how they are used_ -- The problem is that in SQL no reserved word exists in isolation. For example, I can't use the `FOREIGN KEY` reserved word outside of a `CREATE TABLE` or an `ALTER TABLE` statement. Any example showing `FOREIGN KEY` is liable to be obscured by the use of either `CREATE` or `ALTER` in the example.

Comment: I didn't mean in complete isolation, just using a minimal number of other reserved words to show how the chosen keyword works. Something like that could be available after a click on a word in your interactive diagram, though.

Comment: @JeroenMostert numbered stored procedures go back to at least SQL Server 7.0 and probably earlier. The earliest the documentation "applies to" ever states is 2008. E.g. See `SELECT` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql

Comment: @MartinSmith: as long as we're talking about documentation that's helped us -- wouldn't it be great if we always documented every version we still know about instead of pretending that all versions we no longer support have completely ceased existing? This is one of Microsoft's most annoying habits in the documentation. :-P (As an aside, it would also be nice to make a list of features that have been "deprecated" for the longest time -- I'm more surprised when a deprecated feature actually *is* removed.)

Answer (score 11):

Anything that's on http://sommarskog.se/, but the articles on [dynamic SQL](http://sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) and on [error handling](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) in particular as the two topics I most link to in answers or comments. These are large, intricate topics with a lot of real-world applications and considerations that are not covered by the existing documentation beyond the basics. Even when you can give specific, narrow answers to questions covering one particular aspect ("why is my transaction not rolling back despite this error?") these are the pages you go to when you want to give people the fishing rod rather than the fish.

If, as I now realise, the question refers exclusively to content actually created on SO Docs, I can be brief in that I've never used it. I'd still like to mention Erland's site as exemplary stuff, though it obviously doesn't need to be copied as-is to SO Docs (as it already exists). A brief search on SO for "dynamic SQL" within the SQL Server tag yields only dubious and bare-bones examples using `EXEC` with concatenated strings, with no discussion at all on why you'd use it, when you'd use it and the efficiency and security aspects of various approaches.

The major problem with documentation primarily (or exclusively) based on samples or examples is lack of context: "how do I", for example [how do I supply columns to search at runtime](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) is often just a way to roll into a topic that turns out to be far more involved than just "copy and paste this piece of code", since one size does not fit all. If a sample would just leave you with more questions on how to apply it to your particular situation, it's great if the documentation goes to the trouble of addressing that while demonstrating (as Erland's does).

The big challenge with writing in-depth documentation like this is that it requires good people to write it. Just as how 9 women can't produce a baby in one month, you can't get good documentation like this by having 20 authors bash on it with incremental updates. You need a few *good* authors willing to put in the legwork of substantially writing the topics, and edits will provide only marginal improvements, like fixing typos/dead links and minor changes for new versions -- in much the same way as answers are usually edited on SO. For exactly that reason, documentation like this probably "can't be done" on Documentation, as it doesn't fit the open model well (the ur-example of Wikipedia notwithstanding, as Wikipedia has the benefit of being able to confine itself to facts reported elsewhere.) Nevertheless, that's the kind of documentation I find myself needing the most, aside from nitty-gritty documentation that mentions the syntax or required permissions for a command (which the existing documentation covers).

Answer (score 10):

I don't use SQL much, of any form. Which probably makes me a good candidate for evaluating documentation and references from the perspective of someone who's already good at programming, but not at programming *that*.

I have two resources I've used with regard to SQL: the SQLite website, and The Definitive Guide to SQLite book. by Michael Owens.

I'll go over the strengths and weaknesses of both.

---

The Definitive Guide to SQLite is absolutely excellent if you have absolutely no idea what a relational database is. It covers the mathematical foundations of the relational model, and it covers how that model is applied to SQLite. It does this, in my estimation, very well.

Chapter 4, SQL, should be required reading for *anyone* who is writing teaching materials for newbies. This is where the theory presented in prior chapters gets applied to the actual SQLite. They present lots of complex examples of selections, joins, etc, really going over all of the options of the fiendishly complex `SELECT` command.

The later chapters of the book are OK. Not particularly great as a reference (especially since it's somewhat out-of-date). But they give you a good foundation of the API.

The thing I'd say this book was lacking is not concepts, but *idioms*. This book taught me the structure of an SQL database, but it didn't teach me how to use it to accomplish things. For example, how do I make tables have a column that effectively contains an array of strings?

Common SQL idioms are not touched on at all. That may be outside the boundary of such a book, but they are still important to know.

---

The SQLite website is decent reference documentation. It's highly comprehensive (though I can't agree with others who say that the giant flowchart for the `SELECT` command is useful), and it is up-to-date with the latest SQLite releases.

One of the failures in the website is ease of navigation. Sometimes, concepts and pages that should be linked aren't, and there is no easy navigation between pages outside of inline links. As a simple example, the CREATE table page has no direct links to the ALTER table page, even though they are obviously related.

A more pernicious problem is that information is highly localized. Here's what I mean. An SQLite datatype is conceptually like a constraint. And yet, you won't find a link to the page for SQLite's constraints on the [datatype page](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). In fact, there *is no page* that covers SQLite's constraints specifically. They're listed on the [page for the `CREATE` table command](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#constraints). Why?

Because it belongs there; after all, constraints are part of table creation. But it also belongs on its own separate page. And it belongs on the `ALTER` table command too, though restricted since you can't add certain kinds of constraints that way.

What they really need is a way to put the same information in multiple places, but only *edit it* in one place. This is something I do frequently on the OpenGL Wiki, through MediaWiki transclusion. For example, the [Built-in Variables](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Built-in_Variable_(GLSL)) page lists all of the variables in each shader stage that GLSL defines. But each of the pages for those shader stages *also* lists those variables. I only write the information once; they're transcluded from there into the various other pages.

Comment: Unfortunately for mainstream software culture, structuring semantics presentations via syntax, man or FAQ is a terrible idea. Moreover most people are not competent to organize or write documentation. Like software projects, quality requires Brooks's conceptual integrity. SO Articles (currently only available in SO Teams), because of their limited authorship, might help fulfill this role.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly documentation, but these questions

- [dropping default constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430456/how-to-drop-sql-default-constraint-without-knowing-its-name) and
- [getting the identity of an inserted row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row)

are ones that I've come back to multiple times.

They are tasks that I have had to do multiple times, but are not obvious from the IDE. There isn't any meaningful Intellisense for `SCOPE_IDENTITY`.

Another factor is that they're hard to test locally. I want to be confident that constraints will be deleted, but I only have the names generated on my instance. I want to be confident that I'll get the identity of the row I just inserted, but it would be a lot of work to set up a race condition. The explanation, votes, and discussion are helpful for judging the accuracy of the answers.

Comment: Good to know. If you have a moment to think about it, what makes those questions useful? Is there anything about how they are presented that could be better? (I have some ideas, but I can't be sure we agree what they are. ;-)

Comment: Hmm, along those lines, it might by interesting to look at what people's favourite questions are in the `tsql` tag. I'm not a SEDE wizard myself though :/

Comment: @JonEricson I added some explanation, hope that helps!

Comment: @JornVernee SEDE not needed. In the `tsql` search results page, just click the [votes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) tab or the [frequent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) tab. Since the results of these queries are arguably indicators of the "tasks" of greatest interest to the T-SQL community, one could ask how T-SQL "documentation" might differ and thereby create additional value.

Answer (score 2):

There's the huge set of StackOverflow questions which have been asked already which can be a guide to what sort of issues people have. For example, for [T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql?sort=votes), the most popular question has been viewed 2.7 million times. And it is a pretty generic question about a feature of T-SQL, so it would make sense in docs. It's not an issue about a specific issue somebody is encountering, but rather about "how to do something".

Might be worth exploring along side direct answers from the community.